# Can you dynamically import ReactComponent SVGs?

Tags: reactjs, svg

I currently have a series of SVGs that if I import using the following syntax I can then treat like react components and pass options like colour, stroke width etc when they are rendered:

```
import { ReactComponent as SomeSvg } from '../../images/svg/some.svg';
import { ReactComponent as OtherSvg } from '../../images/svg/other.svg';
```

I can then call something like the following to create a dynamically styled piece of image data:

```
let svgComponent = OtherSvg.render().type({
  opacity: 0.5,
  style: {
    color: 'red'
  }
});

let imageDataSource =
  'data:image/svg+xml;utf8,' +
  ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(svgComponent).replace(
    '<svg',
    '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"'
  );
```

This works great but requires me to "hard-code" the imports in my component module.

Is there any way that I can dynamically load these from some arbitrary config? Imagine the definitions object has been loaded from an external json file using require:

```
let definitions = {
  "Something": {
    "svgFileName": "some.svg"
  },
  "Other": {
    "svgFileName": "other.svg"
  }
};

Object.values(definitions).forEach(definition => {
  definition.svgComponent = import('../../images/svg/' + definition.svgFileName); //Not sure how to do an import ReactComponent as SomeName here
});

let svgComponent = definitions["Other"].svgComponent.render().type({
  opacity: 0.5,
  style: {
    color: 'red'
  }
});

//etc.
```